# Order by and Group by statement not working?

Tags: mysql

I have the following statement

```
SELECT
verification_booking.id, verification_booking.reg, verification_booking.status,
verification_updates.ver_id, verification_updates.notes, verification_updates.systime, verification_updates.sysdate,
verification_updates.event
FROM verification_updates
INNER JOIN verification_booking 
ON verification_updates.ver_id = verification_booking.id
WHERE verification_booking.status = 'Open' AND DATE(verification_updates.sysdate) = CURDATE() 
GROUP BY verification_updates.ver_id
ORDER BY verification_updates.systime DESC
```

I am trying to get the last record entered in time period with order by statement, but it is giving me the first record for some reason? Is there an inner join issue or is my statement wrong

Comment: For the same reason, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    verification_booking.id,
    verification_booking.reg,
    verification_booking.status,
    verification_updates.ver_id,
    verification_updates.notes,
    verification_updates.systime,
    verification_updates.sysdate,
    verification_updates.event
FROM
    verification_updates
        INNER JOIN
    verification_booking
WHERE
    verification_updates.systime IN (SELECT 
            MAX(systime)
        FROM
            verification_updates
                INNER JOIN
            verification_booking ON verification_updates.ver_id = verification_booking.id
        WHERE
            verification_booking.status = 'Open'
                AND DATE(verification_updates.sysdate) = CURDATE()
        GROUP BY verification_updates.ver_id)
ORDER BY verification_updates.systime DESC;
```

Comment: The result I am getting is not grouping the ver_id section and it is giving me 4 of the same result times as well?